# C++ compile time counter/accumulator

Tags: c++, constant-expression

I could not find a compile time counter/accumulator to achieve something like the following:

> ```
> #define DECLARE_VAR(type, varName) \
>    type varName;                   \
>    ADD_TO_ACCUMULATOR(sizeof(type));
>
> DECLARE_VAR(float, var1);
> DECLARE_VAR(bool, var2);
> constexpr int total = GET_ACCU_AND_ADD(0);
> static_assert(total == 5);
> ```

So I came up with the following:

```
#define GET_ACCU_AND_ADD_IMPL(number, counterIndex)     \
    summer<counterIndex>::get();                          \
        template<>                                        \
    struct summer<counterIndex+1> {                        \
        constexpr static int get() {                        \
            return summer<counterIndex>::get() + (number);  \
        }                                                     \
    };                                                        

#define ADD_TO_ACCUMULATOR_IMPL(number, counterIndex)     \
        template<>                                        \
    struct summer<counterIndex+1> {                        \
        constexpr static int get() {                        \
            return summer<counterIndex>::get() + (number);  \
        }                                                     \
    }; 

#define GET_ACCU_AND_ADD(number) \
    GET_ACCU_AND_ADD_IMPL(number, __COUNTER__)

#define ADD_TO_ACCUMULATOR(number) \
    ADD_TO_ACCUMULATOR_IMPL(number, __COUNTER__)


template<int tIndex>
struct summer {
    constexpr static int get() {
        static_assert(tIndex == 0, "should not be called/instantiated");
        return 0;
    }
};

template<>
struct summer<0> {
    constexpr static int get() {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Downsides:

- Relies on `__ COUNTER __`
- ?

Feedback is appreciated, maybe there are already better solutions out here?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do, but are you looking for [Simon Brand's "`integral_variable`: A compile-time assignable variable"](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/integral_variable/)?

Comment: It would be nice to know what you want to achieve with this: how will `total`be used?